# Check if a getElementById is empty

Tags: javascript

I have a `if else` function in javascript:

```
if(document.getElementById('lengthFront').value > 4 && document.getElementById('lengthFront').value < 296 && document.getElementById('lengthBack').value > 4 && document.getElementById('lengthBack').value < 296)
{
    document.getElementById('param_length').classList.remove('bg-danger');
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('param_length').className = "bg-danger";
}
```

Bu I need an extra check so it won't be executed when `lengthFront` or `lengthBack` is empty, I have tried different solutions but I can't find the right way to get it working. All my solutions are pointing to else

I have tried to add:

```
document.getElementById('lengthFront') == '' && document.getElementById('lengthBack') == '' &&......
document.getElementById('lengthFront') == false && document.getElementById('lengthBack') == false &&......
document.getElementById('lengthFront') == null && document.getElementById('lengthBack') == null &&......
document.getElementById('lengthFront') =!= undefined && document.getElementById('lengthBack') != undefined &&......
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score -1):

```
if(document.getElementById('lengthFront') && document.getElementById('lengthFront').value != '')
```

First condition makes sure that the element exists, second one makes sure it's value is not empty.

Answer (score -1):

For the most concise and readable approach to dealing with DOM elements that may or may not exist and that may not have a valid value if they do exist, might I suggest you leverage two friends: logical AND `&&` which you can use as a faux null coalescing operator, and the 'conditional ternary' operator `?:` in such a way that you can check for null and blank string, and then assign a default value (0) or the element value, all in the initial assignment statement. Also, you'll want to ***avoid multiple redundant `getElementByXXX` queries*** by simply assigning the result to a variable (better readability, less typing, performs faster):

```
var lengthFront = document.getElementById('lengthFront');
var lengthBack = document.getElementById('lengthBack');
var paramLength = document.getElementById('param_length');

lengthFront = (lengthFront && lengthFront.value != '') ? lengthFront .value : 0 ;
lengthBack = (lengthBack  && lengthBack.value != '') ? lengthBack .value : 0 ;

if(lengthFront > 4 && lengthFront < 296 && lengthBack > 4 && lengthBack < 296) {
    paramLength && paramLength.classList.remove('bg-danger')
} else {
    paramLength && (paramLength.className = "bg-danger");
}
```

Comment: What are the advantages?

Comment: downvoter (or anyone),  care to explain the thumbs down?